# How to plot paired data with different colors considering their labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colors, scatter

I have two lists, the first one is a list of paired data (data contains 76 pairs) and the second one is the corresponding label (label contains 76 numbers between 0 to 11).I need 11 different colors.
I need to plot each of these paired data with a specific color considering its label.
The two lists are like these:

```
data=[[2,6],[1,7],[3,8],[4,6],[7,9]] 
labels=[1,0,0,2,2]
```

I'm beginner to python. any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data=[[2,6],[1,7],[3,8],[4,6],[7,9]] 
labels=[1,0,0,2,2] #labels should have the same length as data
x = [i[0] for i in data] #separates the pairs into just the x component
y = [i[1] for i in data] #separates the pairs into just the y component

plt.scatter(x, y, c = labels, s = 50, cmap = 'rainbow')
plt.show()
```

The "c = labels" means "use the labels values to choose the colors"
The "s = 50" determines the size of the points, adjust as necessary so you can see the colors
The "cmap = 'rainbow'" determines the colormap you're using for the colors.

Here's the colormaps with their names for matplotlib: [matplotlib colormaps](https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html)